# Suitable verb for gently stroking someone's butt

Tags: word-request

What would be a better word than "touch" when talking about gently stroking someone's butt?

In this context, it's a husband touching her wife's butt (she's ok with this, BTW), and not during sex or anything. Instead, he's touching her butt while she's doing something mundane like brushing her teeth and he's walking past her. A Japanese word that matches what the person wanted is なでる, which [translates](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A7%E3%82%8B&eng=&dict=edict) as "to brush gently; to stroke; to caress".

I thought "goose" would be suitable, but [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/goose#Verb) says that's for sharply poking or pinching, which isn't the case here. Would "fondle" or "caress" be suitable, or is that more associated with sex? There's also "grope", but does that imply a lack of physical co-ordination, or being unable to see what you're touching?

Comment: +1, but I think this question belongs to English Language & Usage.

Comment: *Groping* can imply lack of co-ordination (or vision), but it also has strong associations with (usually *unwanted*) sexual touching. *Goose* is usually equally unwanted, but doesn't always carry such strong sexual overtones. *Brush gently, stroke, caress, fondle* are all fine.

Comment: A _goose_ is pinch or grab, usually surprising and unexpected; whether or not it's welcomed or unwanted would depend on who was doing it, and the relationship between the gooser and the goosed. _Fondle_ suggests a gentle grab or grope, but it's more prolonged – unlike a _goose_, which is short and quick. _Caress_ is a good word for the gentle stroke or brush you describe. P.S. I think this question is fine here, as most native speakers readily understand the differences between goosing, pinching, groping, fondling, stroking, and caressing.

Comment: なでる is also translated "to pet", as in a [cat being petted](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1zcHbwQsQs), so the word itself doesn't necessarily have any sexual connotations.  The literal meaning relevant in this context is *to  lightly slide one's hand along* [something].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides previously suggested terms also consider  *[pet](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pet#Verb)* (“To stroke or fondle (another person) amorously”), although that may have more-amorous overtones than you desire; and *[pat](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pat#Verb)* (“To (gently) tap the flat of one's hand on a person or thing”), as suggested by Trish Rempel in a comment.

You write, “I thought "goose" would be suitable, but Wiktionary says that's for sharply poking or pinching, which isn't the case here.”  Yes, [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/goose#Verb) says “(slang) To sharply poke or pinch someone's buttocks. Derived from a goose's inclination to bite at a retreating intruder's hindquarters.”  This is in accord with FumbleFingers's remark, “Goose is usually equally unwanted, but doesn't always carry such strong sexual overtones [as groping]” and with  J.R.'s, “A goose is pinch or grab, usually surprising and unexpected; whether or not it's welcomed or unwanted would depend on who was doing it, and the relationship between the gooser and the goosed.”

You write, “Would "fondle" or "caress" be suitable, or is that more associated with sex?”  For *[fondle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fondle#Verb)* wiktionary offers two senses, “To touch or stroke lovingly [eg] Mothers fondle their babies” and  “To grasp [eg] The lovers fondled each other”.  I've always thought of  *fondle* in the former sense, and was unaware of its “To grasp” sense until now, so would not have assigned such overt sexual overtones to it.  Wiktionary also offers several senses for  *[caress](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caress#Verb)*, including  “To touch or kiss lovingly; to fondle [eg] She loves being caressed by her boyfriend” and “To show and act on deep closeness shared with another person”.  I think *caress* in the latter sense probably is the best word here.

Comment: The word _pat_ could work, because it does not have an amorous overtone, but it's more of a tapping motion than a brushing motion.

Comment: Until I researched this question, I didn't know that fondle could have *non* sexual overtones!

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes there are a couple of words or a phrase that can tell more than a word . . .

***Gentle stroke***

***absent-minded caress***

***playful pat***

or more descriptive: ***his hand grazed over the curve of her butt***

Comment: The last one sounds like something out of Mills and Boon!